# Error "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 22 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'July' to data type int."

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  
    CAST((DATEDIFF(day, '21 JULY 2017', CAST(DAY(DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, -1, '21 JULY 2017'), 0) -1) +
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATENAME(MM,'21 JULY 2017'), 120), 10) + 
        CAST(YEAR('21 JULY 2017') AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME))) AS INT ) * (2.08 / DAY(EOMONTH('21 JULY 2017')))
```

I want to calculate the no of day calculation.

But I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'July' to data type int.

Comment: Instead of `'21 JULY 2017'` use `'2017-07-21'`.

Comment: What do you want to calculate? Seems like your sql is quite complicated, I think if you explain what your goal is we can probably help you better.

Comment: It's okay to show your attempt, but I doubt that the current query is the best way to achieve your goal. It's difficult to know though because you haven't *told us* what you're trying to achieve. Ideally, [edit] the question and add some *sample data* and your *expected results*.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Actually scenario is as below  .. for 1 month (say july) employees gets 2.08 days leaves (full calender month)if he joins on 21 july 2017.. so he should get only 10 days prorated leaves from 21 july-31 july.. here i am calclulating this only   (31 july-21 july ) / (2.08 * no of days in month)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the expected output is, or what is it that you try to calculate, I figured out that the cause to the error you get is that you try to concatenate int values with string values, using the `+` sign.
In these cases, SQL Server tries to implicitly convert the string values to int values to perform an adding operation (instead of the concatenation operation you want).
Therefor, I've added casting to varchar as well as spaces so that the casting to datetime will work.

```
Select  cast((Datediff(day,'21 JULY 2017', CAST(cast(day(dateadd(mm,DateDiff(mm, -1, '21 JULY 2017'),0) -1) as varchar(10)) +' '+
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATENAME(MM,'21 JULY 2017') , 120), 10) +' '+ 
        cast(year('21 JULY 2017') as varchar(4)) as datetime))) as int) * 
        (2.08/DAY(EOMONTH('21 JULY 2017')))
```

The output I've got is `0.6709677419350`, but since I have no idea what is your goal, I don't know if it's correct.

Since I've had some spare time, I was able to re-write your query and get the exact same results with a much simpler query:

```
Select  Datediff(day,'21 JULY 2017', EOMONTH('21 JULY 2017')) * 
        (2.08/DAY(EOMONTH('21 JULY 2017')))
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)